# Content Block Safari rule check

Tags: ios, swift, mobile-safari

As you know in iOS9 Apple added Content Blocking for Safari. Rules for that content blocker are written in JSON format. If one of the rule is incorrect Safari stops processing all rules and you can't know what rule caused that problem.

Is it any way to check what exact rule caused Safari to stop processing all rules for content blocking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and finally Safari prints Content Blocker logs since OSX 10.11.1 beta 3. So if you are already updated to that or newer version of OSX, then you should be able to see if Content blocker prevents something from displaying in Safari's Console.

Unfortunately, it doesn't print which rule exactly is triggered.
So I wrote a simple function that takes Content Blocker JSON file and url and finds if any rule blocks that url.

```
NSString *searchedString = @"https://r5---sn-3c24lx7y.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id=o-AFLsF5lK1HyyhDtjGx567tfBd4Dmuia67Exbs7LURFrZ&sparams=clen,dur,expire,gir,id";

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"/path/to/your/adblock.json"];
NSArray *rules = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
for (NSDictionary *rule in rules){
    NSDictionary *action = rule[@"action"];
    if ([action[@"type"] isEqualToString:@"block"]){
        NSString *urlFilter = rule[@"trigger"][@"url-filter"];
        NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern: urlFilter options:0 error:nil];
        NSArray* matches = [regex matchesInString:searchedString options:0 range: NSMakeRange(0, searchedString.length)];
        if (matches.count > 0){
            NSLog(@"match %@", rule);
        }
    }
}
```